# passing variable inside append tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery I am using 'append' function to append 'a' tag in to div which is working fine

```
$('#div1').append('<a href=./1.php>'+test+'</a>');

var test= "<script>";
test+="alert("hello1")";
test+="<";
test+="/script>";
```

this code shows hello1

my problem is that I want to pass variable with test like this

```
$('#div1').append('<a href=./1.php>'+test(variable)+'</a>');

var test= "<script>";
test+="alert(variable)";
test+="<";
test+="/script>";
```

Is there anyway or am I doing it wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: why add javascript inside an anchor tag? why not add it directly to `body` (or even better to `head`). Do you not want to call a functiuon when the user clicks on the anchor?

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? This is just going to alert straight away when you append the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [javascript functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) that returns a string;

```
function test(variable) {
    return "<script> alert('" + variable + "'); </" + "script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do something on user click:

```
$('#div1').append('<a href="1.php">link text</a>').click(function() {
    alert("hello1");
});
```